# How To Provide Video Source From a Text File in Open CV Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, artificial-intelligence

I want to use video Capturing in Opencv with providing video path or camera path from a text file,
is their any possibility to Provide Video Source From a Text File in Open CV Python

Comment: What does the "camera path" look like, exactly?

Comment: camera path means :-  vs = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://user:password@183.82.121.207:554/Streaming/Channels/101/')    OR   cv2.VideoCapture('0')                                                                                                                  video path means :-  vs = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

Comment: I Want Provide this ('rtsp://user:password@183.82.121.207:554/Streaming/Channels/101/') from a text file.:

Answer (score 0):

```
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(open('file.txt').read())
```

In text file just write your : -
Video file name with extn. : -  Video.mp4

or

Camera path : - rtsp://User_Name:Password@127.0.0.1/Streaming/Channels/501